# Python 2 vs. 3 re.sub() regex replace difference

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm trying to regex replace n occurrences of a letter with a single letter. Should be simple enough, as [I know regular expressions](https://xkcd.com/208/). Python 2.7.15 works as expected:

```
>>> re.sub('x*', 'y', 'xxxxx')
'y'
>>> re.sub('x*', 'y', 'zxxxxxz')
'yzyzy'
```

But Python 3.7.2rc1 gives me:

```
>>> re.sub('x*', 'y', 'xxxxx')
'yy'
>>> re.sub('x*', 'y', 'zxxxxxz')
'yzyyzy'
```

Using `'x+'` as pattern partially works around the issue, but obviously does not work for 0-length matches.

Comment: I can't reproduce your result in Python 3. I get `'y'` and `'yzyzy'`, respectively.

Comment: @Tomothy32 I do reproduce it in 3.7.2 on Linux, what version of python3 are you using?

Comment: I can't reproduce in Python 3.4.5.

Comment: Found a machine with Python 3.5.3, works like v2.7 as expected

Comment: @eyllanesc Never mind, just realized I was using my 3.6.7 interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an intentional change in python 3.7. From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=regex#re.sub):

> Empty matches for the pattern are replaced when adjacent to a previous
>   non-empty match.

Using that terminology, I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53642571/retrieving-python-3-6-handling-of-re-sub-with-zero-length-matches-in-python-3) detailing how to regain the old functionality.